# Redirecting IP address to domain address

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

Google has indexed the IP address of my site rather than the domain, so now I'm trying to set up a 301 redirect that will redirect the IP address and all subsequent pages to the domain.

I currently have something like this in my .htaccess file (however don't think it's working correctly?):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.567\.890
RewriteRule (.*) (domain address)/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've used various redirect checker tools and keep getting the message: "... not redirecting to any URL or the redirect is NOT SEARCH ENGINE FRIENDLY"

Am I doing something wrong or is there something else I should be trying?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12.34.567.890$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If either the old or new url won't dereference, then usually the Google crawler complains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern for your httphost cond (the following represent the end of the first line)

```
!^example\.com [NC]
```