# Google search showing AWS elastic IP instead of domain URL

Tags: google-search, amazon-aws

I have one domain codesharehub.com that is hosted on AWS EC2 with elastic IP 52.66.150.16, I have added A record in DNS to map domain with IP but on google search of codesharehub I get IP address instead of domain URL. I am not able to understand what is the issue, please help. I have attached screenshot  for reference. [image]

Comment: See [Prevent request via IP address of server](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68307/prevent-request-via-ip-address-of-server) and [Redirecting IP address to domain address](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31603/redirecting-ip-address-to-domain-address) and [redirect the site IP address to the domain name](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71156/redirect-the-site-ip-address-to-the-domain-name) and [Remove indexed IP address from Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119194/remove-indexed-ip-address-from-google)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to set your server config to force HTTP requests to redirect to HTTPS. HTTPS cannot be done with only IP, it has to be a domain. So, this would make it basically impossible for Google to give an IP.

**Edit:** It seems like it already does this. This might be Google taking time to update. In Google console you can request a reindexing by the Googlebot.

Comment: This won't completely solve the problem.  They need to redirect HTTP and HTTPS requests that use the IP address or an unrecognized host name.

Answer (score 1):

Your site has not crawled Proper in Google. Google now takes 10 to 30 days to crawl a webpage or website, so if you can request through Google boot through reindexing in Google console. This will cause Google to crawl your site and maybe your problem.